# default value "1484-002" is evaluated as 1482 instead of displaying as string

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have some vba code on my form load that searches for the most recent record in a table then sets the default value for a field on the form to the value from that record.

The values are always in the format of 1484-002. The correct value is being found no problem but when it is displayed on the form it is 1482. This is leading me to believe that it is being treated as a formula and subtracting 2 from 1484 instead of displaying like a string.

The field in the table is set to short text. My form is bound to the table.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim lastID as Integer

lastID = DMax("ID", "Drilling Detail")

Pattern.DefaultValue = DLookup("[Pattern]", "Drilling Detail", "[ID] = " & lastID)
```

How do I get the proper 1484-002 displayed?

Comment: Try: `= "'" & DLookup(...) & "'"`

Comment: Can you try `Pattern.DefaultValue = "2000-500"` and see what it says afterwards?

Comment: But don't you want to increase this sequence by 1?

Comment: Are you opening a form to enter related dependent records for a master record that was just created? If so, why not use form/subform arrangement?

Answer (score 0):

Text values need delimiters. And maybe handle case of empty table.

`Me.Pattern.DefaultValue = "'" & Nz(DLookup("Pattern", "Drilling Detail", "ID = " & Nz(DMax("ID", "Drilling Detail"),0)), "1484-001") & "'"`

Can possibly eliminate the intermediate DMax() on the ID field and just DMax() Pattern.

If you really need to increase the sequence by 1:

```
Dim strNext As String

strNext = Nz(DMax("Pattern", "Drilling Detail"), "1484-000")

Me.Pattern.DefaultValue = "'" & Left(strNext, 5) & Format(Mid(strNext, 6) + 1, "000") & "'"
```

OnCurrent event is a better location if you need to increment the sequence for multiple records entry.

Advise not to use spaces in naming convention. Better would be DrillingDetail or Drilling_Detail.

Comment: Yes the text delimiters solved it! The Pattern number is not always increasing so DMax() on Pattern won't work. It is the name of a drill pattern and is sometimes different like 1188-009.

Comment: So ID is an autonumber type field? I have read warnings not to depend on autonumber to always be increasing and positive, although I have never observed otherwise.